# How to get an element's style after waiting for a delay using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling

I need to check the value of the `font-weight` property of an `li` element after a certain amount of time following a click event. The code below loops through all the `li` elements, so whenever a `click` `event` is fired on one of them, it should get the value of the `font-weight` property and output it to the console, but actually it returns a blank line:

[image]

```js
const pages = document.querySelectorAll("#pagination li");

pages.forEach(page => page.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let fontWeight = e.target.style.fontWeight;
    console.log(fontWeight)
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(fontWeight)
    }, 1000)
}));

document.querySelector('#pagination li:nth-of-type(3)').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
window.getComputedStyle(e.target).fontWeight;
```

I'm not entirely sure why this happens but I think it has something to do with the way the style was applied to the element.

Comment: the 'bold' style whenever  is the current page (pagination), like so: 
for (let i = 1; i <= (numberOfItems / itemsPerPage); i++) {
  let $li = $("<li></li>").html(i);
  $li.css({"display": "inline",  "cursor": "pointer", "margin-left": "10px"});
  if (currentOffset === itemsPerPage * (i - 1)) {
    $li.css("font-weight", "bold");
  }
  $("#pagination").append($li);
}
I test your solution but it output the same font-weight value, even it is bold after the click event

Answer (score 0):

There was no HTML code with your code snippet, so I added some HTML to work with the JavaScript code you gave.

I don't know why `document.querySelector('#pagination li:nth-of-type(3)').click()` does not work for you. Probably there is something wrong with the HTML you are using. It works with the HTML below and, after clicking RUN in the Code Snippet, `bold` appears in the console.log

The following line in your code will read the font weight at the time of the click:

`let fontWeight = e.target.style.fontWeight;`

so your first `console.log` will be correct. However, your second `console.log` will only return this very same value, because you are not accessing the `fontWeight` attribute from `e.target`. I can only guess that there were no font weights set on your `li` elements or your CSS selectors were not working properly. That's probably why nothing will be returned when you click on a number.

In the code below, we can store a reference to `e.target` in the `liElement` variable and then we can access this inside the `setTimeout` callback. In this way, the code will access the `liElement` twice, once on click and again one second later. If the font weight changes then you will see this in the `console.log`

```js
const pages = document.querySelectorAll("#pagination li");
const fontWeightOnClick = document.getElementById("fontWeightOnClick");
const fontWeightAfter1Second = document.getElementById("fontWeightAfter1Second");

pages.forEach(page => page.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let liElement = e.target;
  console.log(liElement.style.fontWeight, "on click");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(liElement.style.fontWeight, "after 1 second");
  }, 1000)
}));

document.querySelector('#pagination li:nth-of-type(3)').click()
```

```css
#pagination {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pagination">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">3</li>
  <li style="font-weight: 800;">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li style="font-weight: bolder;">10</li>
  <li style="font-weight: 600;">11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
</ul>
<p>Click on '3', '4', '10' or '11' to return the weight. Clicking on any other number will not return the weight</p>
```

Comment: The bold font-weight is added dynamically once the page number is clicked, so actually, I can retrieve the original font-weight as you did with your code but not after it's changed to bold.

Answer (score 0):

````js
/*
```*/ //400 - norm, 700 - bold in many browser apps
var timing=1000;
for(itr=1;itr<7;itr++){
  ment = document.createElement('li');
  ment.setAttribute('onclick','if(this.id%2==0){this.style.fontWeight=`bold`}');
  ment.id=itr;
  ment.innerText=itr;
  
  document.body.appendChild(ment);
  }
 var eventually;
 var code='console.log(getComputedStyle(eventually.target).fontWeight)';
  document.body.setAttribute(`onclick`,`eventually=event;setTimeout(code,timing)`); /*
```*/
````

*Why this code*:

It is simplified, without pagination, but still providing the ability to change the font weight (when you click an even `li`, it becomes bold like a current page link).

After the second of a click, you `getComputedStyle` of the item as a number 400 or 700 most often in browser alerted. Try it.